# There is not any documentation for unique filter of the Indicative Node module. How can I use it?

Tags: node.js, validation, module, unique, adonis.js

The indicative Node module does not have any documentation about "unique" filter. It's mentioned in the introduction, but not documented.
This is a part of the example in the main page:

```
const rules = {
  email: 'required|email|unique:users',
  password: 'required|min:6|max:30'
}
```

This is the example and the reference: https://indicative.adonisjs.com/docs/syntax-guide#_defining_rules

And if it's not available, how can I write it myself?

**UPDATE:**

The author mentioned that there is not any unique rule in the Indicative module. That sample was using adonis-validator module.
How can I write unique rule or use *adonis-validator* with *Indicative*?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing column name in the users table to check unique email.

The correct syntax is: `unique:<table_name>,<column_name>`

So, if you want `email` column is unique with `email` value get from request, you need to change `rules` to:

```
const rules = {
  email: 'required|email|unique:users,email',
  password: 'required|min:6|max:30'
}
```

Hope this help!